Signature vs commensurability
If a closed oriented $4n$-dimensional manifold $M$ has an orientation-reversing homeomorphism, then the signature $\sigma(M)$ of the intersection form vanishes. More generally, $\sigma(M) = 0$ if $M$ is commensurable with a non-orientable orbifold $O$ (i.e. some compact $M'$ covers both $M$ and $O$).
Does there exist $M$ with $\sigma(M) = 0$ such that $M$ is not commensurable with any non-orientable orbifold? Does there exist such an aspherical $M$?

I’m pretty sure that one could find Gromov-Piatetskii-Shapiro examples of hyperbolic 4-manifolds which have this property. Arithmetic hyperbolic 4-manifolds are commensurable with non-orientable orbifolds. The GPS examples are obtained by “interbreeding” incommensurable hyperbolic manifolds by cutting and pasting along isometric totally geodesic hypersurfaces. By making sure that non-orientable symmetries don’t agree along the gluing, I think one could arrange that they do not cover a non-orientable orbifold. But of course this would require a careful construction.

Sounds interesting! Let's see if there'll be a simpler argument (w/o Mostow, Margulis, etc), even without the asphericity requiremet. Otherwise, I'll assume it as an answer.

I’m guessing one could arrange signature 0 non-aspherical by taking a connected sum of manifolds with opposite signatures and which are not related by a reflection. I think a connected sum of non-isometric complex hyperbolic manifolds of the same volume (but one with orientation reversed ) should work.

I see, thanks, so the non-aspherical case appears rather simple. Just to understand better: is it the same with two manifolds with opposite signature and, say, different Euler characteristic, or are you using complex hyperbolicity?

For complex hyperbolic manifolds (compact ball quotients), signature is $1/3$ of Euler characteristic. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogomolov%E2%80%93Miyaoka%E2%80%93Yau_inequality and is proportional to volume. Complex hyperbolicity is also a sufficient condition to say that the fundamental group is a free product and any homemorphism must respect this free product, so preserves the two factors (up to conjugacy of each factor).

Ok, so I guess this is the answer! And If I got it this works for any n, just replacing "same volume" with "opposite signature"
